# Fourier transform 4 times = original function (from Bracewell book)

Tags: fourier-transform, transform, fourier

I was glancing through *"The Fourier Transform & Its Applications"* by Ronald N. Bracewell, which is a good intro book on Fourier Transforms. In it, he says that if you take the Fourier transform of a function 4 times, you get back the original function, i.e.
$$\mathcal F\Bigg\{ \mathcal F\bigg\{  \mathcal F\big\{  \mathcal F\left\{  g(x) \right\} \big\} \bigg\} \Bigg\} = g(x)\,. $$

Could someone kindly show me how this is possible? I'm assuming the above statement is for complex $x$, and this has something to do with $i^0=1$, $i^1=i$, $i^2=-1$, $i^3 = -i$, $i^4=1$?

Thank you for your enlightenment.

Comment: "Equivalent to time inversion" -- this got me thinking. If you have the Fourier transform of a particle's wave function, would the inverse Fourier transform give you the wave function of the anti-particle?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll use the non-unitary Fourier transform (but this is not important, it's just a preference):

$$X(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt\tag{1}$$

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega\tag{2}$$

where (1) is the Fourier transform, and (2) is the inverse Fourier transform.

Now if you formally take the Fourier transform of $X(\omega)$ you get

$$\mathcal{F}\{X(\omega)\}=\mathcal{F}^2\{x(t)\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}d\omega\tag{3}$$

Comparing (3) with (2) we have

$$\mathcal{F}^2\{x(t)\}=2\pi x(-t)\tag{4}$$

So the Fourier transform equals an inverse Fourier transform with a sign change of the independent variable (apart from a scale factor due to the use of the non-unitary Fourier transform).

Since the Fourier transform of $x(-t)$ equals $X(-\omega)$, the Fourier transform of (4) is

$$\mathcal{F}^3\{x(t)\}=2\pi X(-\omega)\tag{5}$$

And, by an argument similar to the one used in (3) and (4), the Fourier transform of $X(-\omega)$ equals $2\pi x(t)$. So we obtain for the Fourier transform of (5)

$$\mathcal{F}^4\{x(t)\}=2\pi\mathcal{F}\{X(-\omega)\}=(2\pi)^2x(t)\tag{6}$$

which is the desired result. Note that the factor $(2\pi)^2$ in (6) is a consequence of using the non-unitary Fourier transform. If you use the unitary Fourier transform (where both the transform and its inverse get a factor $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$) this factor would disappear.

In sum, apart from irrelevant constant factors, you get

$$\bbox[#f8f1ea, 0.6em, border: 0.15em solid #fd8105]{x(t)\overset{\mathcal{F}}{\Longrightarrow} X(\omega)\overset{\mathcal{F}}{\Longrightarrow} x(-t)\overset{\mathcal{F}}{\Longrightarrow} X(-\omega)\overset{\mathcal{F}}{\Longrightarrow} x(t)}$$

Comment: In fact, $(6)$ suggests a fantastical idea about how one can design an amplifier that converts computation into amplitude gain: just take the non-unitary Fourier transform of $x(t)$ 4 times to amplify the signal by a factor of 39 or so (or  31 dB gain)!

Comment: @DilipSarwate: How can I have missed that! I'd contact a patent attorney before someone here steals this brilliant idea!

Comment: Unitary factor should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2 \pi}}$, mistyped in the last paragraph.

Comment: Too late! A patent has already been granted for an even better method (using FFT to reduce total computation from $4N^2$ to $4N\log N$ instead of plain vanilla Fourier transform).

Comment: Thanks. Also, are there similar interesting cycles like this for other transforms, e.g. Laplace?

Comment: @sambajetson: With the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) you get $\mathcal{H}^2\{f(t)\}=-f(t)$.

Comment: Could someone prove that the above Fourier Transform 4 times property applies also to higher dimensions, specifically to the 2D case?

Comment: Link to analogous question about higher dimensional case: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/fourier-transform-4-times-original-function-2d-and-higher

Comment: i haven't seen this question or answer before.  i would sau that *"constant factors"* are not *"irrelevant"*.  because of that i would recommend the unity Fourier transform.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand this point, but Eqn. (3) is the definition for inverse Fourier transform right since the variable of integration is omega though the integral kernel is the same. So it's like we are applying Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms on the same function? Not the Fourier transform twice.

Comment: No - eqn (2) is the inverse Fourier transform. Eqn (3) is arrived at by using (1) twice and then comparing it to (2) and noticing they are equal when you replace $t$ with $-t$.

Comment: thank you David. For me the variable of integration is different between Eqn. (1) and Eqn. (3) and then I see it as Fourier and inverse Fourier. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nnn Please do not add questions as "answers". To be able to comment, you need more reputation. There are many ways to gain rep. Try editing things or adding tag descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer, the original question also asked whether there is any relationship with $i^0=1, i^1=i, i^2=-1, i^3=-i$, and the answer is: yes, these four numbers are the four possible eigenvalues of the unitary Fourier transform, and the corresponding eigenfunctions are the Hermite functions. The deeper reason for this lies in the fact that unitary transforms are generated by a Hermitian operator via [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) and the Hermitian operator for the Fourier transform is the number operator N of the quantum harmonic oscillator. Correspondingly, each Fourier transform corresponds to a transform resulting from the [Mehler kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel) of the number operator for a time span of $t=\pi/2$ such that after four transforms the original function is obtained again. [Fractional Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform) correspond to other time spans. For a detailed account of these facts cf. i.a. the text leading up to section 7.5.10 of the book [Integral Transforms in Science and Engineering](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-0872-1) by Kurt B. Wolf (also available [here](https://www.fis.unam.mx/%7Ebwolf/integraleng.html)), or this article on [Hermite Functions and Fourier Series](https://doi.org/10.3390/sym13050853).